# Tkinter press button with command

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter

Say I have an app with number buttons. I have binded the keyboard numbers to the app and they do the same stuff as if I've pressed the button in the app. What I would like to do is when I press the key on the keyboard, make the buttons on the GUI pressed down as if I clicked there. How do I acheive this ?

Comment: Have you done any research or tried anything you can share with us?

Comment: Google mostly, haven't found what I was looking for. I googled: "tkinter press a button with command". I might be searching for a bad expression, since I dont know what is it called. Nothing interesting to share I'm afraid.

Comment: I feel like this has been answered before I jsut dont know what to look for.

Comment: Also using invoke is not good since it doesnt make the buttons pressed down.

Comment: @JozefMéry: please remember it is always better to show some sample code even if it doesn't do everything you want. Because: 1) it usually make answerers gain time (copypaste, run code, "oh I see the problem", edit, copypaste back) 2) it shows you have done some work

Comment: I figured as much. I guess that was Mr. Oakley's problem. Thanks though. I can add my working solution as an answer to prove my advance and that the people's help here was not in vain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm says:

> To make an ordinary button look like it’s held down, for example if you wish to implement a toolbox of some kind, you can simply change the relief from RAISED to SUNKEN:

```
b.config(relief=SUNKEN)
```

Therefore you can write:

```
import tkinter as tk

def mimicClick( _button):
    _button.config(relief=tk.SUNKEN)
    _button.after(100, lambda :  _button.config(relief=tk.RAISED))

master = tk.Tk()
buttons = []
for i in range(10):
    b = tk.Button(master, text= i)
    b.grid(row = i // 3, column = i % 3, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    buttons.append(b)
    master.bind(str(i), lambda e, i = i: mimicClick(buttons[i]) )

master.mainloop()
```